# Loading Polyline from JSON and displaying on a Map

Tags: javascript, database, json, postgresql, google-maps

First of all, i am a beginner in development with the Google Maps API, and want to know what is the best way to show in a map a route made from a polyline wich takes its coordinates from a table in a PostgreSQL database?.

I have two tables, one called "routes" and another one called "route_dots"

The "routes" table contains the following fields:

```
-id --> Unique ID of the route,
-sport_id --> ID of the sport,
-user_id --> ID of the user who upload the routes,
-title --> title of the route,
-description --> description of the route,
```

the "route_dots" contains
    -id  --> unique ID of the spot,
    -route_id --> ID of the route,
    -coord_lat --> LAT,
    -coord_lon --> LON,
    -magic number --> Order of the points of the route,

in other web sites i reached a solution that i could generate a JSON file with all the information of the route such as the LAT and LNG coordinates, title, description and then let the map read that information for displaying the routes.

What i want to do is to generate an array with all the LAT and LNG coordinates taken from coord_lat and coord_lon fields, wich contains the coordinates, along with the title of the route and the description.
The "magic_number" field, contains the order of the points.

how do i generate a JSON file with all the information above and plotting then that file in a Map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PostgreSQL 9.1 or higher you can use a json type (first delivered in 9.2 out of the box, but a backport is available for 9.1).

If you are using this functionality, you basically have three steps:

1. Define a PostgreSQL user defined type to represent the data structure you need.  Note that tuple types can have tuple types, and even arrays of tuple types as attributes as of PostgreSQL 8.4 so you can create deep data structures as you need.
2. Write a query that outputs this data structure
3. Wrap it in row_to_json()

The complexity is beyond a working example however.